# Basics: Defining sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think it is a really basic question, but I've been struggling to get it right.

a) A set of pairs: for every $x$ there is exactly one partner and it can't be partner with itself.

My solution:

$E_1=\{(x,y)|\forall x \in V_1 \exists!y \in V_1 \land x\neq y\}$

b) For every $y$ there are exactly $y$ number of pairs and $x$ can't be partner with itself:

$E_2= \{(x,y)|\forall y \in V_2: $#$E_2 = y \land x\neq y\}$

c) number of pairs where $x$ is the first component can't be equal to the number of pairs where $x$ is the second component, $x$ can't be partner with itself and there has to exist at least one pair.

$E_3= \{(x,y)|....\}$

I'm not allowed to use the dot notation (e.g.: $M=\{1,2,3,...\}$)

I'm not sure about $E_2$. For $E_3$ I don't know how to define that.

Comment: What was the exact original question? Note that the solutions are not unique.

Comment: When you have $\{(x,y)\;|\;\ldots\;\}$, you don't want to quantify over $x$ and $y$ in the "$\ldots$". What you have written as $E_1$ is that $(x,y)$ is in your relation if $V_1$ has exactly two elements.

Comment: @Berci There can't be any self loops.Find an edge set sot that for every $v \in V_n \\ a) d^+(v) = 1 \\ b)d^-(v) = v \\ c)d^+(v) \neq d^-(v) \land d(v) \geq 1$